# VBA - Possible to select multiple sheets across workbooks?

Tags: vba, selection

I'm trying to print to a single PDF a selection of worksheets that spans multiple workbooks. The way I've printed multiple sheets to a single PDF before is by selecting all of them. Hence my question -- is it possible to select multiple sheets *across* multiple open workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Sheets From Mutli-WorkBooks and Publish Them to PDF File

```
' Usage:
' PublishRangePDF(Thisworkbook, fileName) : Will Publish the entire Workbook
' PublishRangePDF(AvtiveSheet, fileName) : Will Publish all selected worksheets
' PublishRangePDF(Range("A1:H100"), fileName) : Will Publish Range("A1:H100")


Sub PublishRangePDF(RangeObject As Object, fileName As String, Optional OpenAfterPublish As Boolean = False)
    On Error Resume Next
    RangeObject.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub BatchPDF()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim arrWorkbooks(5)
    Dim ar As Variant

    Set arrWorkbooks(0) = Workbooks("publish-multiple-workbooks-pdf.xlsm")
    arrWorkbooks(1) = Array("Sheet1", 2, "Sheet3", 4)

    Set arrWorkbooks(2) = Workbooks("Dictionary 4.xlsm")
    arrWorkbooks(3) = Array("Current", "Previous", "Previous Pivot")

    Set arrWorkbooks(4) = Workbooks("InkEdit Answer.xlsm")
    arrWorkbooks(5) = Array(1, 2, 3)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrWorkbooks) Step 2

        If wb Is Nothing Then
            arrWorkbooks(i).Sheets(arrWorkbooks(i + 1)).Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Else
            arrWorkbooks(i).Sheets(arrWorkbooks(i + 1)).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        End If

    Next


    PublishRangePDF wb, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\excel-data.pdf"

    wb.Close False
End Sub
```